# forEach is not working for items structure of data from store of ExtReact

Tags: javascript, extjs, extreact

I am trying to iterate through data of ExtReact store to get the data from the store using `.getData()`.

Subsequently, when I try to iterate through the items, I don't get any results for a single item. It's like it is empty.

Here is the result of `data.items` when I `console.log` the whole array:

[image]

However, when I go through this array using `forEach` I am getting nothing.

This is the code of `forEach` loop:

```js
if(userShortCutData.items !== undefined){
    console.log(userShortCutData.items);
    userShortCutData.items.forEach(function(item){
        console.log(item); //nothing is consol.log-ed;
        console.log(item.data); //nothing is consol.log-ed;
        console.log(item._user); //nothing is consol.log-ed;
    });
}
```

Comment: Does it log undefined? Or does it just not log anything as if the forEach is never run?

Comment: Nothing is logg-ed as if the ForEach has never been ran...

Comment: Add another condition in `if` like `userShortCutData.items.length`

Comment: It's likely that the console log is showing you an "evaluated just now" object, but when the code is run `items.length` is likely to be `0`.

Comment: Ok when I write if condition:
if(userShortCutData.items !== undefined && userShortCutData.items.length !== 0)

it doesn't even enters the if condition.. Any other ideas? I will try answer below in more details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the underlying list of records as an array:

```
store.getRange().forEach(r => {
    console.log(r.id);
});
```

To use the built in store method:

```
store.each(r => {
    console.log(r.id);
});
```

You can use a load or refresh listener (depending on what you need) on the store to wait until data has been processed:

```
store.on('refresh', () => {
    // do the magic();
});
```

Comment: How to access data inside store.on? Because inside that I can't use store.data.items right?

Comment: The same way you do it outside, either by calling `getRange` or `each` or any other store function.

Comment: Ok to do:

store.on("refresh", () => {
     store.getData().getRange()....
});

or?

Comment: Don't use `getData` at all. Use `getRange` or `each` directly on the store.

Comment: Aha ok, I will try that... :)

Comment: What to use for map function? For rendering? Can you please add that to the post?

Comment: `getRange()` returns the records as an array, as it says in the post.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is the difference between load and refresh?

Comment: `refresh` :-  Fires when the data cache has changed in a bulk manner (e.g., it has been sorted, filtered, etc.) and a widget that is using this Store as a Record cache should refresh its view. 

`load` :- Fires whenever the store reads data from a remote data source.

For more details you can refer [doc](https://docs.sencha.com/extreact/6.5.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#event-load)

Comment: Is there some listener that I can use to load data from the store before first render?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. If you want to defer rendering until the store loads, then that's an entirely different question. You could check `store.getCount()` and render some loader as appropriate.